# what's that before first IDR in 264 (not sps pps)

Tags: ffmpeg, h.264, libx264

I used ffmpeg and libx264 to encode my video,when I print the AVPacket data,I found  there is something only exist before the first IDR.Could someone tell me what's that,thanks.

```
0 0 1 6 5 ff ff 73 dc 45 e9 bd e6 d9 48 b7 96 2c d8 20 d9 23 ee ef 78 32 36 34 20 2d 20 63 6f 72 65 20 31 34 38 20 72 32 36 34 33 20 35 63 36 35 37 30 34 20 2d 20 48 2e 32 36 34 2f 4d 50 45 47 2d 34 20 41 56 43 20 63 6f 64 65 63 20 2d 20 43 6f 70 79 6c 65 66 74 20 32 30 30 33 2d 32 30 31 35 20 2d 20 68 74 74 70 3a 2f 2f 77 77 77 2e 76 69 64 65 6f 6c 61 6e 2e 6f 72 67 2f 78 32 36 34 2e 68 74 6d 6c 20 2d 20 6f 70 74 69 6f 6e 73 3a 20 63 61 62 61 63 3d 31 20 72 65 66 3d 31 20 64 65 62 6c 6f 63 6b 3d 31 3a 30 3a 30 20 61 6e 61 6c 79 73 65 3d 30 78 33 3a 30 78 31 31 33 20 6d 65 3d 68 65 78 20 73 75 62 6d 65 3d 32 20 70 73 79 3d 31 20 70 73 79 5f 72 64 3d 31 2e 30 30 3a 30 2e 30 30 20 6d 69 78 65 64 5f 72 65 66 3d 30 20 6d 65 5f 72 61 6e 67 65 3d 31 36 20 63 68 72 6f 6d 61 5f 6d 65 3d 31 20 74 72 65 6c 6c 69 73 3d 30 20 38 78 38 64 63 74 3d 31 20 63 71 6d 3d 30 20 64 65 61 64 7a 6f 6e 65 3d 32 31 2c 31 31 20 66 61 73 74 5f 70 73 6b 69 70 3d 31 20 63 68 72 6f 6d 61 5f 71 70 5f 6f 66 66 73 65 74 3d 30 20 74 68 72 65 61 64 73 3d 34 20 6c 6f 6f 6b 61 68 65 61 64 5f 74 68 72 65 61 64 73 3d 34 20 73 6c 69 63 65 64 5f 74 68 72 65 61 64 73 3d 31 20 73 6c 69 63 65 73 3d 34 20 6e 72 3d 30 20 64 65 63 69 6d 61 74 65 3d 31 20 69 6e 74 65 72 6c 61 63 65 64 3d 30 20 62 6c 75 72 61 79 5f 63 6f 6d 70 61 74 3d 30 20 63 6f 6e 73 74 72 61 69 6e 65 64 5f 69 6e 74 72 61 3d 30 20 62 66 72 61 6d 65 73 3d 30 20 77 65 69 67 68 74 70 3d 31 20 6b 65 79 69 6e 74 3d 31 32 20 6b 65 79 69 6e 74 5f 6d 69 6e 3d 31 20 73 63 65 6e 65 63 75 74 3d 34 30 20 69 6e 74 72 61 5f 72 65 66 72 65 73 68 3d 30 20 72 63 3d 61 62 72 20 6d 62 74 72 65 65 3d 30 20 62 69 74 72 61 74 65 3d 32 30 30 30 20 72 61 74 65 74 6f 6c 3d 31 2e 30 20 71 63 6f 6d 70 3d 30 2e 36 30 20 71 70 6d 69 6e 3d 30 20 71 70 6d 61 78 3d 36 39 20 71 70 73 74 65 70 3d 34 20 69 70 5f 72 61 74 69 6f 3d 31 2e 34 30 20 61 71 3d 31 3a 31 2e 30 30 0 80
```

Answer (score 0):

That is user_data_unregistered SEI with libx264 version info and params. And if you look at it as text you will see: `x264 - core 148 r2643 5c65704 - H.264/MPEG-4 AVC codec - Copyleft 2003-2015 - http://www.videolan.org/x264.html - options: cabac=1 ref=1 deblock=1:0:0 analyse=0x3:0x113 me=hex subme=2 psy=1 psy_rd=1.00:0.00 mixed_ref=0 me_range=16 chroma_me=1 trellis=0 8x8dct=1 cqm=0 deadzone=21,11 fast_pskip=1 chroma_qp_offset=0 threads=4 lookahead_threads=4 sliced_threads=1 slices=4 nr=0 decimate=1 interlaced=0 bluray_compat=0 constrained_intra=0 bframes=0 weightp=1 keyint=12 keyint_min=1 scenecut=40 intra_refresh=0 rc=abr mbtree=0 bitrate=2000 ratetol=1.0 qcomp=0.60 qpmin=0 qpmax=69 qpstep=4 ip_ratio=1.40 aq=1:1.00`

Comment: i developed the python script RemoveSeiInH264Stream.py
 to remove user-data SEIs (all SEIs with sei_type=5), look at the section "Removal Specific SEI Message from H264/AVC Elementary Stream" of http://www.ramugedia.com/useful-python-scripts